# IPC-B-25A test board schematic

Tags: pcb-design, schematic, ipc

I need to design an IPC-B-25A IPC multipurpose test board.

I have only following board image.

Board features are below:

- Solder mask - None
- FR4 Tg=175°C
- Size - 4"x4.5" (10x11.4cm)
- Thickness 0.062" (1.6mm)
- Single layer board
- Connector fingers 0.156" pitch (4.0mm)

Can somebody help me with the schematic of it?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you will be able to create this from a schematic. You need to draw these structures manually.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Do you there is some kind of reference document regarding track width and spacing?

Comment: I strongly suspect there **are** reference documents. You just need to search for them.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson couldn't find any reference documents!.. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The IPC-B-25A Test Board is often times used to evaluate interactions between solder masks, solder paste, and fluxes. It is also used to test conformal coating of PCBs to measure their protective properties regarding partial discharge in humid environments.

You can buy the Gerber Files on the official IPC shop (here https://shop.ipc.org/ipc-a-25/ipc-a-25-gerber-files/Revision-a/english), as it is their intellectual property and published by IPC. At the time of writing, the cost is $161.00.